Ubuntu 24.04 installation freeze
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 from a bootable flash drive into a new Dell Inspiron, but it does not proceed, on clicking in the "Next" button. It freezes and does not proceed, and keeps loading with a spinning circle in the button in the lower right corner of the screen image as if it's stuck.


So, I just tried again, and in the third or fourth time, it worked...
